# What Java library/framework for a game with Baldur's Gate like grapics?

Tags: java, 2d

I really would like to create my own small rpg. It could probably look as simple like baldurs gate. So without fancy 3D stuff.

As language I want to use java (or scala, I thinking about it - the good thing is that all java libs would work with scala too, and there are a lot of java game libs) and I'm not sure what lib/framework should I choose. I thought about [LWJGL](http://lwjgl.org/) or [Slick2D](http://www.slick2d.org/). Because I wont use that much 3D, Slick2D would be the better choice? Or doesn't matter? Any ideas or suggestions? Thank you

Comment: Welcome to gamedev.stackexchange.com. Unfortunately, "What technology to use" questions are considered off-topic here because they are subjective and lead to discussion instead of definite answers. Please read the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) before posting.

Comment: @Philipp Hi. So where else should I ask my question then?

Comment: post on some discussion forum when you would like to read people arguing about the pros and cons of different approaches.

Comment: You could also try our chatroom!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're considering using LWJGL, I would suggest you also check out [libgdx](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/), which uses a LWJGL wrapper for the desktop client. You get the added benefit of an easy port to Android/iOS/HTML5. I don't know how this compares to Slick2D.

Also, even if you are making a 2D game, you should still use 3D-acceleration (e.g. through OpenGL), thought this might be hidden away by the framework so that you don't notice it. 2D graphics in a 3D world doesn't need to be more than looking at a picture on a frame.

Do some research on the various engines you can choose from (this is a google search away). Things to consider is entry-level difficulty, what features you need, and what platforms you are targeting.

Answer (score 3):

I would go for a 3D native approach with LWJGL. When you use OpenGL, all the rendering happens on the GPU, which improves performance. This will allow you to extend your graphics when you think it would be nice to. Using OpenGL allows you everything. This way, you are not limited to some features of a specific library.

On the other side, you will learn how to work with OpenGL.

Don't think that when you use OpenGL, your game can't be 2D.

Comment: Use opengl for the full game, even if at the end everything would be only 2d?

Comment: 2D is just a special case of 3D; any 3D API can also do 2D, and often quite simpler (and more performant) than old-fashioned 2D stuff.